# Is the generation of an AST mandatory to create a compiler?

Tags: c++, parsing, assembly, abstract-syntax-tree

I would like to know if the generation of an AST is obligatory to implement a language, via a compiler for example. I've asked a few times, and each time, it is strongly advised to generate an AST during parsing/lexing of the code.
For example, this:

```
int i = 2 + 3;
```

will have to give this:

```
  = 
 / \    
i   +   
   / \  
  2   3
```

But wouldn't a simple condition of this kind be enough? :

```
if (statement == variable_declaration){
    if (NotDeclaredInCurrentBlock(NameOfVariable)){
        // ...
    }
    else
        Throw "Error: The '" << NameOfVariable << "' variable is already declared";
}
```

I really have no idea how to make a good AST, and I wonder what is simpler AND/OR better performing as a PARSING solution.
And with which solution would the ASM code, for example, be easier to generate?

I'm not completely new in this field, and I've visited quite a few sites about it. I would just like to know which of the solutions (or another one) would be the simplest and most efficient to implement for a toy language; because I guess it's "the AST that wins" for a "real" language.

Comment: No. Generation of AST is not mandatory to create a compiler. Next question, please.

Comment: Well, I don't have any doubts you can do at least _something_ with dirty over 30 year old spaghetti code. If that's a reasonable and conscious way to go is another _pair of shoes_.

Comment: For a simple enough grammar and with a complex enough bytecode, you *can* e.g. straight generate bytecode while parsing, but it makes complex to do almost any transformation/analysis over the input code.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Emscripten sounds impressive. Never been impressed that much to draw into production components seriously though.

Comment: Mandatory? How did you even got that idea? Usually there are at millions of ways how to solve particular task on computer (if there is at least one).  But only some are reasonable, like only tens or hundreds of ideas. For any complex task, like for example compiler, there is never a silver bullet, best in every aspect. Each idea has its own advantages. If AST is strongly advised, then it probably fits in so many scenarios, that you need really some special requirements or idea to avoid it, and not regret it later, but if you are just asking if it's mandatory, get back to algorithms study...

Comment: To extend on my former comment: Something like [this](http://download.cnet.com/TurboC-Simulator/3000-2069_4-75599155.html) comes to mind.

Comment: @TheDude: honestly I don't get what's your point with that link (which is essentially TurboC running in DosBox).

Comment: @MatteoItalia I'd be curious to see the Turbo C++ compiler source code actually TBH.

Comment: How do you tell if the statement is a variable declaration? Most likely by running some kind of parser that generates an AST, then you look in the AST to see if the statement is a variable declaration. You've shown some code that doesn't involve an AST, but what about the **rest** of the compiler?

Comment: That said, there are no compiler police who will arrest you for trying to write a compiler without using any ASTs.

Comment: I just finished writing a compiler for a custom scripting language and I didn't use an Abstract Syntax Tree, so they are not needed for all compilers.

Comment: @immibis: again, if your syntax is simple and unambiguous enough (which is something you should aim for anyway) you can straight generate bytecode and accompanying structures on the fly; we have a full scripting language written like that in a product of ours. See `var` -> the next tokens are variable declarations, modify the stack frame associated with the scope you are currently parsing accordingly. It's not impossible, and it's actually simpler if your problem is simple enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a customised Shunting-yard algorithm for that, this will produce an intermediate like this:

```
<i> create_int <i> 2 3 + :=
```

where `<i>` is some kind identifier. you could achieve this with a list of symbols, where you can look up the id of existing symbols or adding new symbols with the current counter-value as id and incrementing this counter.

you could translate this to x86-code like this:

```
code:
  push 0 ;id of <i>
  push 2
  push 3
  pop eax
  pop edx
  add eax, edx ; +
  push eax
  pop eax
  pop edx
  mov dword [ data + 4 * edx ], eax ; :=
  jmp finally
data:
  vars rd 1 ;number of variables, maximum variable-size is dword
```

as you probably see, this will produce bad code and need to be further optimised. this code nevertheless does not use an ASt, but a stack-based-intermediate-code.